# Countdown application for java

Tags: java

iam a newbie in java and i have a task at hand to make a simple application in java for countdown.

like for ex in that application if i enter the current date it should display how much time is left for christmas or a newyear or any religious occassion ...............

and it should display the result in the format like years/months/days/hours/minutes and seconds........

plz help me for how to go with this...............

thanks in advance.

Comment: I smell homework. No problem in general, but if it the case, please add the homework tag. (and show what you've got so far)

Comment: Nonsense Andreas_D.  This is a potential multi-million dollar iPhone app.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

First start with a [hello world tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html). After that move on [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library since it's much more usable than the standard Java time/date/calendar. If you need further help do not hesitate to post a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Yep, joda time is a great API for manipulating date and time, very good advice imo

Answer (score 0):

How to go?

Let the user [input](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) the date,
Calculate the difference from the inputted date to the occasions-dates and [output](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) them

The dates of the occassions you can put in a [properties file](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) that you read on launching the application

See [Formatting dates](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for formatting

Answer (score 0):

The task is pretty straightforward. You need solutions for the steps

1. Capture user input (`Scanner` class, includes presenting a message to the user
2. Convert user input to a `Date` (includes rejecting invalid data)
3. Calculate the 'distance' to another date (like christmas)
4. Print the result (convert the Date distance to a readable message)

1., 2. and 4. can be done in the main method, for 3. I'd implement a separate method. like `private static Date getDistance(Date earlier, Date later)`